# Is ${\lVert x\rVert} ^2$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is ${\lVert x\rVert} ^2$?
What I did so far is:

Suppose the function is differentiable. Then there exists a linear map $v:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ such that 
$$
\lim_\limits{h\to0}{{\lVert a+h\rVert}^2-{\lVert a\rVert}^2-vh\over {\lVert h\rVert}}=\\
\lim_\limits{h\to0}{<a+h,a+h>-{<a,a>}-vh\over {\lVert h\rVert}}=\\
\lim_\limits{h\to0}{2<a,h>+||h||^2-vh\over {\lVert h\rVert}}=0\Rightarrow\\
vh=\lim_\limits{h\to0}{2<a,h>+||h||^2\over {\lVert h\rVert}}
$$ 
This is a part where I am actually stuck. I don't know hot to proceed. I would truly appreciate any kind of relevant reference.

Comment: In $\lVert a+h\rVert^2 - \lVert a\rVert^2$, which is the part that is linear in $h$?

Comment: I am afraid I didn't entirely get you. Are you suggesting I made an unjustified move? Or drawing my attention to a certain component?

Comment: Oh I get you. Let me take that into account.

Comment: Your last line doesn't make sense, the right hand side could not depend on $h$ if it were well-defined, so the left hand side couldn't either. Before that, you just overlooked something and I tried to point that out to you without naming it.

Comment: You should prove that $v(h) = 2\langle a,h \rangle$ satisfies the definition of the derivative at $x =a$.

Comment: I try to follow what you say. It is just that I don't really come by any form of linearity. Both components are squared.

Comment: I am a little swamped, but is $||h+h||^2=4||h||^2$ linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\lim_\limits{h\to0}{2<a,h>+||h||^2-vh\over {\lVert h\rVert}},\ $ by inspection, if you take $v(h)=2<a,h>$, you will get the result. Then, by uniqueness of the limit, $v$ must the the derivative. Of course, you need to show that $v$ is linear but that's trivial.

Comment: Doesn't it make all vectors differential depend on $a$? I am confused. I mean, in theory, it should work, but I don't see how one arrives at $2x_1+...+2x_n$ from $2<a,h>$, except for $2<x,(1,..,1)>$

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot the differential is respective to the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Using coordinates $x=(x_1,…,x_n)$,
$$||x||^2 = \bigl( \sqrt{x_1^2 + …. + x_n^2} \bigr)^2 = x_1^2 + … + x_n^2
$$
So yes, it is differentiable, since it is a polynomial function of the coordinate functions.